# Unity 2D Can i upload a picture from in game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. I'm trying to use unity to help make an AI interface to match children and their parents using a Model i already trained. Now all i need to do is make an interface for that. I'm relativity new to Unity, and C#. All i want to do is to upload files from in game and display them. Is there anyway i can do that? I think it would be like uploading a new material and switching the sprite's material to that, but I'm not sure how to do that in C#. I tried looking around on the web, but all things i found weren't for in-game stuff. Essentially, all i need is a "Choose file" thing similar to HTML. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by upload files from in game? Do you mean let children and their parents upload from their computer? And on which platform?

Comment: If the answer I provided was correct then please mark it as accepted. If not feel free to ask for more details in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel.html) which returns a string that is the path of the file the user selected. Then you can load the image as a texture, just look at the example in the documentation I linked.